# converting PDF to TIFF using ghostscript but not writing file to disk

Tags: python, pdf, python-imaging-library, ghostscript, tiff

I know that ghostscript can convert pdf to tiff and even has [python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghostscript) but I'm wondering whether there is a way to avoid writing the resulting tiff to disk (`-SOutputFile=/path/to/file.tiff`. Rather I want to keep the resulting tiff in memory and use it as a PIL image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, no, not using the standard devices. That's because the strip size of the TIFF file (and potentially other entries in the TIFF header) can't be written until after the compressed bitmap has been created because the sizes aren't known. So you need to be able to seek back to the beginning and update the header.

Now you could modify the standard TIFF output devices so that they maintain the output in memory, rather than writing to disk, but that's not how they currently work.